# python subprocess sub thread does not exit?

Tags: python

the following code is strange:

```
def exec_shell(args, pipe = True):
    pre_fun = None
    if pipe == True:
        pre_fun = lambda: signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, signal.SIG_DFL)

    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        preexec_fn = pre_fun)
    (out, err) = process.communicate()
```

when i execute a complicate shell script,
if i set the pipe is true:
   the err will be :
        A thread exited while 2 threads were running
if i set pipe false the err will be : broken pipe

who can help me ? thanks

Comment: What are you passing the function as `args`? Setting the argument `pipe` to True just sets the default handler for the SIGPIPE signal, which would otherwise kill the process - hence a different error. So I would guess that whatever command `args` is tries to write to a pipe that gets closed and your command gets terminated with SIGPIPE. You might try running `args` on the command line and see if you get a broken pipe error.

Comment: @EricAppelt  command  run ags does not have a broken pipe, but the command is executing a shell script file, but did have some redicrections ...

Comment: It is hard to tell what the problem might be without knowing more about what `args` is, but you might try adding an argument `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`. Be careful, though - you should generally not use this if `args` is unsanitized input supplied by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplier **os.popen()** function. Example from my program:

```
import os
manifest = os.popen("aapt dump badging " + apk).read() #running command
for info in manifest.splitlines():
    ...  # extracting values
```

Also, subprocess module has a bug: if in *subprocess.Popen()* you specify non-ascii path, then error will occur.

Comment: But you can try with os.popen))